# Flatting a list

Tags: prolog, dcg

I need to write a function that flat a list.

For example:

```
flat([ c , [[[]]] , [] , k] , X).
X=[c,k]
```

this is what I did:

```
    flat([],[]).
    flat([[A] |B] , R) :- flat([A|B],R).
    flat([[]|L],L1) :- flat(L,L1).!
    flat([[A|L]|W],R) :- flat([A|L],U), flat(W,W1), append(U,W1,R).
    flat([A|L], [A|L1]) :- flat(L,L1).
```

I know why it is not true but I do not know how to do that.
thanks.

**EDIT:**
almost work:

```
    flat([],[]).
flat([[]|L],L1) :- flat(L,L1).  --- i think something here missing
flat([[A|L]|W],R) :- flat([A|L],U), flat(W,W1), append(U,W1,R).
flat([A|L], [A|L1]) :- flat(L,L1).


?- flat([c , [[[]]] , [] , k],C).
C = [c, k] ;
C = [c, [], k] ;
C = [c, [], k] ;
C = [c, [], [], k] ;
C = [c, [[]], k] ;
C = [c, [[]], [], k] ;
C = [c, [[[]]], k] ;
C = [c, [[[]]], [], k].
```

Answer (score 1):

```
flatten(List, FlatList) :-
    flatten(List, [], FlatList0), !,
    FlatList = FlatList0.

flatten(Var, Tl, [Var|Tl]) :-
    var(Var), !.
flatten([], Tl, Tl) :- !.
flatten([Hd|Tl], Tail, List) :- !,
    flatten(Hd, FlatHeadTail, List),
    flatten(Tl, Tail, FlatHeadTail).
flatten(NonList, Tl, [NonList|Tl]).
```

Here is swi-prolog solution by Jan Wielemaker and Richard O'Keefe,
the code can be found in prolog's library directory, in lists.pl file.

Answer (score 1):

Code edited (see comments)

Another possibiliy, using DCG :

```
flat(L, FL) :-
    flat(L, FL, []).

flat(X) -->
    {var(X)},
    !,
    [X].

flat([]) --> 
    [], 
    !.

flat([X | T]) -->
    flat(X),
    !,
    flat(T).

flat(X) --> [X].
```

Now we get :

```
 ?- flat([[a,b,c,d|r]], FL) .
FL = [a,b,c,d,r] .


 ?- flat([1,2,[3,4]],L).
L = [1,2,3,4] .

 ?- flat([1,2,[3,4]],[1,2,3,4]).
true .

 ?- flat([ c , [[[]]] , [] , k] , X).
X = [c,k] .
```

Comment: Very nice! Consider using phrase/2 as the official interface to DCGs. Personally, I would also put the !/0 outside the braces and place it on its own line. I think DCGs are a very nice way to handle this elegantly.

Comment: Come to think of it, I would use ( { is_list(X) } -> flat(X) ; [X] ).

Comment: Both: `flat([[a,b,c,d|r]], FL)` succeeds with `FL = [[a,b,c,d|r]]`. Intended?

Comment: Surely not, however, [a,b,c,d|r] is not a proper list.

Comment: Then take `flat([[[a]]|_], FL)`, which is a partial list containing lists.

Comment: `?- flat([1,2,[3,4]],L).` produces 

`L = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, []] ;

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, []] ;

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, [], []] ;

L = [1, 2, 3, [4]] ;

L = [1, 2, 3, [4], []] ;

L = [1, 2, [3, 4]] ;

L = [1, 2, [3, 4], []]  ...`

Comment: Last edited (I hope). I learned a lot from your comments, thanks !

Comment: @joel76: A general comment to using the toplevel: If the toplevel asks you for another answer, always type SPACE to see if there is another solution. @Will Ness already showed you some problems. Maybe consider `flat([], FL)` as a minimal example!

Comment: or ';', in SWI Prolog <http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(3,'2.1.2',swi('/doc/Manual/quickstart.html'))> .

Answer (score 0):

That bang (...flat(L,L1).!...) it's a typo, isn't it?

You could study a [good implementation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=flatten/2) from SWI-Prolog, that exposes its code and gives what's expected:

```
?- flatten([ c , [[[]]] , [] , k] , X).
X = [c, k].
```

Otherwise, try to debug with a simple case to see where your code, once cleaned, fails.
BTW, your code seems to works, just yields more solutions, you need to prune some unwanted path:

```
?- flat([c , [[[]]] , [] , k],C).
C = [c, k] ;
C = [c, [], k] ;
C = [c, [], k] ;
C = [c, [], [], k] .
...
```

**edit** here is code from library(lists) of SWI-Prolog

```
%%  flatten(+List1, ?List2) is det.
%
%   Is true if List2 is a non-nested version of List1.
%
%   @deprecated Ending up needing flatten/3 often indicates,
%           like append/3 for appending two lists, a bad
%           design.  Efficient code that generates lists
%           from generated small lists must use difference
%           lists, often possible through grammar rules for
%           optimal readability.
%   @see append/2

flatten(List, FlatList) :-
    flatten(List, [], FlatList0), !,
    FlatList = FlatList0.

flatten(Var, Tl, [Var|Tl]) :-
    var(Var), !.
flatten([], Tl, Tl) :- !.
flatten([Hd|Tl], Tail, List) :- !,
    flatten(Hd, FlatHeadTail, List),
    flatten(Tl, Tail, FlatHeadTail).
flatten(NonList, Tl, [NonList|Tl]).
```

Your code seems fairly correct WRT your comment:

```
?- flat([1,2,[3,4]],[1,2,3,4]).
true ;
false.
```

Comment: where can I see the implement of SWI-prolog?
By the way, My example is almost work.
but this flat([1,2, [3,4]] , [1,2,3 ,4]).
return false. I know why but i dont know how to write good solution

Comment: thank u again but i need only flatten(List, FlatList)/2 and not
flatten(List, FlatList , _) /3
and you right...this is work with : flat([1,2,[3,4]],[1,2,3,4]).