# List of all the elements in sublist in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I need to write a predicate f(L,R) that succeeds if and only if L is a list containing all terms in R that are not lists.
For example:

```
f(L,[1,2,3,[4,5,6],[[7,8,9]],[]]).
```

Should give:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I wrote a predicate that gives the following result instead:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,[]]
```

Empty lists should not be present in the result. My predicate is the following:

```
f([],[]).
f(V,[H|T]):-  H = [_|_] -> append(L,R,V),
              f(L,H),  f(R,T),!;
              V = [H1|T1], H1=H, f(T1,T).
```

I have two doubts. First of all, the empty lists should not be present in the result. Also I don't know why it does not work if I don't put the cut (!). In fact, if I don't put the cut it gives me the result as above, but if I ask for another result it loops forever. I really don't understand why this should loops.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220567/flatting-a-list/ . Generally, Input is the first argument , Output the second, eg f([1,2,3,[4,5,6],[[7,8,9]],[]], L) ==> L [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: What you are really asking for is [flatten/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=flatten/2). e.g `?- flatten([1,2,3,[4,5,6],[[7,8,9]],[]],L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the empty list, handle that case (discard it).

About the loop: I think the cause could be that you're calling append(L,R,V) with **all** arguments not instantiated: move append after the recursive calls.

Finally, maybe you don't use rightly the 'if then else' construct: I've indented using the usual SWI-Prolog source style, using indentation to highlight 'sequential' calls

```
f([], []).
f(V, [H|T]) :-
    (   H = []      % if H = []
    ->  f(V, T)     %  then discard
    ;   H = [_|_]   % else if H is list
    ->  f(L,H),     %  flat head
        f(R,T),     %  ...
        append(L,R,V)
    ;   V = [H|T1], % else 
        f(T1,T)     %  ...
    ).
```